# How to form bundle name in jstl dynamically

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to load properties file using jstl. But the base name will be formed dynamically.
I am facing issue in creating the base name dynamically.

part of my base name will be present in a pojo which is in session object.
here is my code. The location of my properties file is "WEB-INF/Properties/dynamicname/"

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="properties/<c:out value="${userProfileSessObject.getAppDomain()}"/>.message" />
```

Its gives an error "Unterminated <fmt:setBundle tag".

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its gives an error `Unterminated <fmt:setBundle tag`.

You can not `nest` JSTL tags in other words a JSTL tag can't contains another JSTL tag in any of its attribute, that's why you are getting above error.

Try

```
<fmt:setBundle 
         basename="properties/${userProfileSessObject.getAppDomain()}.message" />
```

Or

```
<fmt:setBundle 
         basename="properties/${userProfileSessObject.appDomain}.message" />
```

*Note:* Use `sessionScope` [implicit object](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html) to find directly in session scope